# SSRS - Report Builder -columns as rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have never used SSRS before.I need to create a new report.Query details from Employee table and display
in the below format for given emplID

```
Emplid            111
EmplName          test
DateofBirth       1/1/1990
DateofHire        1/1/2015
DeptID            1
DeptName          Sales
ManagerSignature  --------------
Signed Date       ------------
```

Also need to add custom fields that are not in the table like ManagerSignature and SignedDate.
I'm not sure how to get the above format.Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to create a report with the two-column format you need is to add a table to the report.

Delete the last column so you only have two.

Right-click on the detail row (with the three lines like a hamburger menu icon) and Insert Row --> Inside Group.

Repeat Inserting Rows 6 more times to create all the detail lines you need.

The Left Column will be used as your Header and the 2nd column for your data. Add your Text headers to the first column and then chose the corresponding data field in the second.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, add your signature and date line as null values so you can select it in your table just like the other values. Then add black bottom borders to those two text boxes to represent the signature/date lines.

```
select 
 Emplid         
, EmplName       
, DateofBirth    
, DateofHire     
, DeptID         
, DeptName       
, null as 'ManagerSignature'
, null as 'SignedDate'
from YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you..How do i get the report in the above format (vertical) ? by default the data is displayed horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have data something like below

[image]

Click on View and Report Data, There you can see your dataset and it'S column as well
[image]

Then go to Design area and then in body section Insert--> Table

[image]

You will have something like below
[image]

Then you will get option to enter data

[image]

Same way keep adding all others as well

Now on first row taye label per hand as below

[image]

At last you will have something like below

[image]

Remove unwanted column cell and row cell.

You will have something like below

[image]

Here's the tip,

Now if you want each record on each page

Click on Row deatils and then go to genral and add EmpId

[image]

and then add pagebreak as below

[image]

final result on each page each record result

[image]

[image]